# Postgres 11, receiving broken pipe, if stays inactive

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, connection-pooling

Spring application is logging broken pipe occasionally. To deal with stale connections issue, application is already using -

> *testWhileIdle=true* and *validationQuery=SELECT 1*

Stack trace -

```
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:333)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
            ... 133 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
            at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:514)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendSync(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1363)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:304)
            ... 143 more
     Caused by java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

A vague feeling, if application stays inactive for while, then it might be giving problem connecting to backend or vice-versa. But since can not reproduce this issue locally, it is hard to point.

Comment: Is this error happening while you are actually trying to use the connection?  Or does it happen when the app server is executing validationQuery, and the app server just logs this activity?  If the latter, then it just seems to be validationQuery doing exactly what it is there to do.  Can you find log messages in the PostgreSQL server's log file that correspond to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the timeout of idle connection higher.

```
idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 30000
```

in postgresql.conf

But your error seems strange to me. I would probably check if you dont have way to many connection as well.

On the spring-boot side you could try adding the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
   spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
   spring.datasource.validation-interval=30000
```

you could try reducing the validation interval. I set it to the default one there

Hope it helps